# Nested configuration not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot

I'm working on a project using spring boot, and we've just upgraded to version 1.4.0.RELEASE. As part of the version upgrade, we've started using the @SpringBootTest annotation on our abstract integration test class. After reading [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config), it sounds like we should be able to use a nested @TestConfiguration-annotated config class to override bean definitions during specific tests. This is not working for us, and instead the non-test bean we are trying to override is still being used.

Interestingly, it seems like usages of the mock test bean and the production bean are actually intertwined within the same test, as if both beans exist side by side in the application context. Also, it seems like the order in which the integration tests run somehow affects this behaviour. I'm wondering if this is something we've misconfigured, or if there is something else going on.

edit:

The abstract class that the integration tests inherit from looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles({"local", "test"})
public abstract class BaseIntegrationTest {

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    protected int port;
}
```

The integration test that we are seeing the strange behaviour in looks like this:

```
public class WebhookProcessorIT extends BaseIntegrationTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class Config {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public WebhookTask webhookTask() {
            return mock(WebhookTask.class);
        }
    }

    // sometimes the mock above is used and sometimes
    // the actual production bean is used
    @Autowired
    private WebhookTask task;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        when(task.process(any())).thenReturn(true);
    }

    // tests ...
}
```

And this is what the root application context class looks like:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

edit:

I have also tried using `@MockBean`, like so:

```
public class WebhookProcessorIT extends BaseIntegrationTest {

    @MockBean
    private WebhookTask task;
```

but I get the same result when the tests run. I can see that Spring is trying to override the production bean with the mock I am providing when I look at the logs during the test setup:

```
build   15-Sep-2016 09:09:24    2016-09-15 09:09:24 [34mINFO [0;39m [36m[DefaultListableBeanFactory][0;39m (main) Overriding bean definition for bean 'productionWebhookTask' with a different definition
```

however when it comes to test execution, i can still see the production bean being used:

```
build   15-Sep-2016 09:09:29    2016-09-15 09:09:29 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[WebhookSupplier][0;39m (WebhookProcessor) Received webhook with ID '1234' from queue.
build   15-Sep-2016 09:09:30    2016-09-15 09:09:30 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[WebhookSupplier][0;39m (WebhookProcessor) Received webhook with ID '5678' from queue.
build   15-Sep-2016 09:09:30    2016-09-15 09:09:30 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[ProductionWebhookTask][0;39m (WebhookProcessor) Received webhook with ID '1234' for processing // production webhook task bean still being used for webhook '1234'
build   15-Sep-2016 09:09:30    2016-09-15 09:09:30 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[WebhookSupplier][0;39m (WebhookProcessor) Deleting webhook with id '5678' from queue. // mock bean causes production logic to be skipped and we just delete webhook '5678'
// More logs from production webhook task operating on webhook with id '1234' and causing the test to fail
```

Comment: do you mean that occasionally a real bean is run instead of the mocked one or what?

Comment: Can you share your test class so we can understand more around your specific setup?

Comment: @ShadyRagab yes it seems that way.

Comment: @enbdk  it would be a little bit tricky having the two configuration class runs because the TestConfiguration will not replace the production class. Both of them will be in the context.

Comment: @enbdk I don't really understand the log lines, but would you provide your method stubbing and expectations too?

Comment: @ShadyRagab What the test is doing isn't really that important. The test is failing because process() isn't being called twice on the mock, which we assert for. It's only called once against the mock and the other time the actual production webhook task is used.

I've added the snippet of code where the method is mocked to the question.

Comment: @enbdk Have you been able to figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you can annotate your test beans with **@Profile("test")** and your real ones with @Profile("production")

and in your properties file put the property **spring.profiles.active=test**

from documentation

> Unlike regular @Configuration classes the use of @TestConfiguration
>   does not prevent auto-detection of @SpringBootConfiguration.
>
> Unlike a nested @Configuration class which would be used instead of a
>   your application’s primary configuration, a nested @TestConfiguration
>   class will be used in addition to your application’s primary
>   configuration.

Comment: I would like not to use profiles in this case, since we have other integration tests that use the production WebhookTask bean, and ideally we would like to be able to use nested config to stub it out only for certain tests.

Comment: Also, i linked that section of the documentation in my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you use Spring Boot version 1.4.0, you can go on use the new introduced annotation **@MockBean** instead of using different configuration classes to mock your original beans. It's straight forward and very suitable to your use case.

[Here you go with an example from the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html)

Comment: I've also tried using the MockBean annotation and I get the same result. I've updated my question again with some comments around this.